# Excel VBA Compiler Constants: Mac Excel 2011 <> VBA7?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm not able to run Excel for Macintosh, but since the Excel VBA compiler constant VBA7 was introduced with Excel (for Windows) 2010, I figured it would apply to Mac Excel 2011 too.

However, apparently this code compiles the "Else" section (intended for Excel 2007) when run on Mac Excel 2011:

```
#If VBA7 Then 
    'Set constants here for Excel 2010 or later:
#Else
    'Set constants here for Excel 2007 or earlier:
#End If
```

So to get it to work for a user who is on Mac Excel 2011, I had to change it to this:

```
#If VBA7 Or Mac Then 
    'Set constants here for Excel for Windows 2010 or later, or Excel for Mac:
#Else
    'Set constants here for Excel for Windows 2007 or earlier:
#End If
```

Does Mac Excel 2011 really not have VBA7, or is that just an omission in the compiler constant?

Answer (score 1):

Excel for Mac still uses VBA 6.5, hence the VBA7 constant does not exist.  This is still the case with Excel Mac 2016 as at v15.11 (150609).

If you really want to differentiate between host Excel Application versions, then you should be using `Application.Version`:

Where:

```
5 = Excel 5
6 = Excel 6
7 = Excel 95
8 = Excel 97
9 = Excel 2000
10 = Excel 2002
11 = Excel 2003
12 = Excel 2007
14 = Excel 2010 and Excel Mac 2011
15 = Excel 2013 and Excel Mac 2016
```

If you want the VBA environment version you can use:-

```
Application.VBE.Version
```